# Django Rest Framework - How to store a GIF image

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-imagekit

I am working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework, and I am facing an issue related to storing and processing GIF images in one of my models.

```
class GiftCardPlan(model.Model):
# ... other fields ...
image = ProcessedImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=giftcardplan_image_path,
                            processors=[SmartResize(480, 290, upscale=False)],
                            options={'quality': 100})
```

serializer

```
class GiftCardPlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(read_only=True)
```

> I want to handle GIF images properly within the GiftCardPlan model.
> I've tried different approaches, but none seem to work as expected. My
> current implementation loses GIF animation during processing.

Comment: I guess something about that `ProcessedImageField` or maybe that `SmartResize` processor is stripping animation. What else have you tried?

Comment: @AKX I comment out the processors= 
but still the issue persists 

# processors=[SmartResize(480, 290, upscale=False)],

Comment: Well, you also have a `quality` there... You'd probably want to look the docs for whatever's providing that `ProcessedImageField`.

Comment: actucally i try comment teh options fields also, but still the movement is gone from the gif